# How to output just the full absolute path to the file from ANsible win_find return values?

Tags: ansible

Using the Ansible win_find module, I want to output just the path to the found files and I am trying this:

```
- name: Find files in directory while searching recursively
    win_find:
      paths: C:\Downloads
      recurse: yes
    register: dwnlds_list

  - name: Display win_find file list result
    debug: var=item.path
    with_items: "{{ dwnlds_list.files }}"
```

However, the output I get is every return value for every found file.

What I would like is just:

```
"C:\\Downloads\\file0"
"C:\\Downloads\\file1"
"C:\\Downloads\\file2"
```

Comment: `{{ dwnlds_list.files | map(attribute="path") | list }}`

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
- name: Find files
  win_find:
    paths: C:\Downloads
    recurse: yes
  register: dwnlds_list

- name: Output file list
  debug: msg="{{ dwnlds_list | json_query('files[].path') }}"
```